# appending foreign key reference in django json response

Tags: python, django, json, django-queryset

during appending the result (appending foreign key ) causes key error

models.py

```
class table1
    id = models.IntegerField( primary key=TRUE)
    ref = models.ForeignKey('table2')

class table2
    name = models.CharField()
    id = models.IntegerField(primaryKey= True)
    address = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
def relation(request)
"""
    some stuff
"""
    query = "query set makes object of table 1"

    result['content'].append([query['ref__address'])
```

the error is

```
Keyerror at /url
ref__address
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)? This is basic stuff.

Comment: yes i have, as far as i remember, i can reference foreign key by using "__"

Comment: Yes, but [only when filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships); not what you have posted here (which isn't even valid Python code)

Comment: what is your query? did you try query.ref.address?

Comment: @sneawo - my query is

    query = table1.objects.filter(ref__address)
    result['content'].append([query['id'],query.ref.address])


--
the error that i get now is

    dict object  has no attribute "ref"

Answer (score 1):

```
def relation(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Table1, pk=pk)
    context= {'content': item}
    return render(request, 'table1/relation.html', context)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^table1/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', relation, name='relation'),
)
```

Your problem seems to be that none of your python was valid.